# KDE Plasma5 widgets by default

Tags: linux, kde, plasma5

**Configuration**

Kubuntu 18.04 
KDE PLasma5 as desktop environment

**Problem**

Is it possible to configure default plasma widgets for new user? So when I create new user on workstation it have preconfigured widgets by default. Or maybe is it possible to install/enable widget for user from CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

```
~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
```

All widgets settings are stored there. You can create a new user, define what do you want, exit session and copy this file to `/etc/skel` (for new users) or copy it to ~/.config of existing users.

You can also create a complete theme for your users. You can see detailed instructions here: `https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Create_a_Look_and_Feel_Package`.